# Android Studio applicationId with upper case

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a live up in Google Play store for about 5 years. It was released with Eclipse and I used upper cases characters in the package name in the store (I now know that it's wrong). Now I am trying to migrate to Android Studio and it fails to install the app to a device due to "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED"

Is there a way to force Android Studio to work with my previous package name or I'm stuck with Eclipse?

Thanks,
Noam

Comment: could you share your manifest please .

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="22"
      android:versionName="2.8.1" package="Aaaa.Bbbb.Cccc"
      android:installLocation="auto">

Comment: i find solution to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188338/why-is-android-studio-having-problems-with-capitalized-package-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by-pass this error by declaring the package name through `Gradle` instead of `Manifest`? For example:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.Example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode x
    versionName "x.x.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: After importing to Android Studio it is defined both in build.gradle:  applicationId "Aaaa.Bbbb.Cccc" and in the Manifest as package="Aaaa.Bbbb.Cccc". Should I delete one of them? If so, where is the actual place that defines the app package for the store?

Comment: If you declare it in Gradle, You don't need te Manifest one @NoamBehar

Comment: I removed the name from the manifest. Still not working. When I switch to lower case in build.gradle I am able to install it to the device. I just can't get rid of this problem.

Comment: I double checked this. It seems that Firebase was the one who had problems with uppercase letters. Once I removed that, I was able to install the uppercase letters app.

Comment: @NoamBehar I didn't know Firebase had a check that overrides this. Good to know, thanks for clarification of that!